# Speeding up matrix row and column operations in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, parallel-processing

I have a positive big matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(abs(rnorm(130000*1000)),nrow=130000,ncol=1000)
rownames(mat) <- paste("r",1:nrow(mat),sep="")
```

The `rownames` of `mat` are associated with a `parent.id`:

```
row.ids.df <- data.frame(row.id=rownames(mat),parent.id=paste("p",sort(sample(13000,130000,replace=T)),sep=""))
```

such that every few rows are associated with the same `parent.id`.

I need to compute these operations for every `row` in `mat`:

1. `mean` of `log` of the row elements
2. `mean` proportion of of that row out of all rows with the same `parent.id`
3. `mean` probit of the proportion of of that row out of all rows with the same `parent.id`
4. `sd` probit of the proportion of of that row out of all rows with the same `parent.id`

Naturally this is the first solution that comes to mind:

```
require(VGAM)
res.df <- do.call(rbind,mclapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) {
  idx <- which(rownames(mat) %in% row.ids.df$row.id[which(row.ids.df$parent.id == row.ids.df$parent.id[which(row.ids.df$row.id == rownames(mat)[x])])])
  data.frame(mean.log=mean(log(mat[x,])),
             mean.proportion=mean(mat[x,]/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum)),
             mean.probit=mean(probit(mat[x,]/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum))),
             sd.probit=sd(probit(mat[x,]/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum))))
}))
```

But I'm wondering if there's any way to achieve this faster.

P.S.

I don't think using `data.table` instead of matrix is the way to go:

```
require(data.table)
require(microbenchmark)
require(VGAM)

set.seed(1)
mat <- data.table(matrix(abs(rnorm(13*5)),nrow=13,ncol=5))
rownames(mat) <- paste("r",1:nrow(mat),sep="")
row.ids.df <- data.frame(row.id=rownames(mat),parent.id=paste("p",sort(sample(2,13,replace=T)),sep=""))

microbenchmark(df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) {
  idx <- which(rownames(mat) %in% row.ids.df$row.id[which(row.ids.df$parent.id == row.ids.df$parent.id[which(row.ids.df$row.id == rownames(mat)[x])])])
  data.frame(mean.log=mean(as.numeric(log(mat[x,]))),
             mean.proportion=mean(as.numeric(mat[x,])/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum)),
             mean.probit=mean(probit(as.numeric(mat[x,])/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum))),
             sd.probit=sd(probit(as.numeric(mat[x,])/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum))))
})))


expr
 df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) {     idx <- which(rownames(mat) %in% row.ids.df$row.id[which(row.ids.df$parent.id ==          row.ids.df$parent.id[which(row.ids.df$row.id == rownames(mat)[x])])])     data.frame(mean.log = mean(as.numeric(log(mat[x, ]))), mean.proportion = mean(as.numeric(mat[x,          ])/apply(mat[idx, ], 2, sum)), mean.probit = mean(probit(as.numeric(mat[x,          ])/apply(mat[idx, ], 2, sum))), sd.probit = sd(probit(as.numeric(mat[x,          ])/apply(mat[idx, ], 2, sum)))) }))
      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 65.08929 66.49415 69.78937 67.70534 70.38044 206.017   100
>
```

Compared to:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(abs(rnorm(13*5)),nrow=13,ncol=5)
rownames(mat) <- paste("r",1:nrow(mat),sep="")
row.ids.df <- data.frame(row.id=rownames(mat),parent.id=paste("p",sort(sample(2,13,replace=T)),sep=""))

require(VGAM)
microbenchmark(df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) {
  idx <- which(rownames(mat) %in% row.ids.df$row.id[which(row.ids.df$parent.id == row.ids.df$parent.id[which(row.ids.df$row.id == rownames(mat)[x])])])
  data.frame(mean.log=mean(log(mat[x,])),
             mean.proportion=mean(mat[x,]/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum)),
             mean.probit=mean(probit(mat[x,]/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum))),
             sd.probit=sd(probit(mat[x,]/apply(mat[idx,],2,sum))))
})))


Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            expr
 df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) {     idx <- which(rownames(mat) %in% row.ids.df$row.id[which(row.ids.df$parent.id ==          row.ids.df$parent.id[which(row.ids.df$row.id == rownames(mat)[x])])])     data.frame(mean.log = mean(log(mat[x, ])), mean.proportion = mean(mat[x,          ]/apply(mat[idx, ], 2, sum)), mean.probit = mean(probit(mat[x,          ]/apply(mat[idx, ], 2, sum))), sd.probit = sd(probit(mat[x,          ]/apply(mat[idx, ], 2, sum)))) }))
      min      lq     mean median       uq      max neval
 10.15047 10.2894 10.69573 10.428 10.69741 14.56724   100
```

Unless applying `as.numeric` each time I want to run an operation on `data.table` row is a bad idea.

Comment: Have you tried data.table?

Comment: Have not. Good idea.

Comment: It's actually not such a good idea - see updated post

Comment: There are some tricks for doing it the data.table way. I am not actually that much of an expert but once akrun or someone sees this they can show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think using data.table instead of matrix is the way to go

Obviously, you have to actually use data.table. It's not a magical wand that optimizes your code without you spending some effort. You need to use data.table syntax.

> I need to compute these operations for every row in mat:
>
> ```
> mean of log of the row elements
>
> mean proportion of of that row out of all rows with the same parent.id
>
> mean probit of the proportion of of that row out of all rows with the same parent.id
>
> sd probit of the proportion of of that row out of all rows with the same parent.id
> ```

I think this might do what you need:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(row.ids.df, mat)
DT <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("row.id", "parent.id"))

DT[, proportion := value / sum(value), by = .(variable, parent.id)]

res <- DT[, .(
  mean.log = mean(log(value)),
  mean.proportion = mean(proportion),
  mean.probit = mean(probit(proportion)),
  sd.probit = sd(probit(proportion))), by = row.id]

all.equal(res[["sd.probit"]], 
          res.df[["sd.probit"]])
#[1] TRUE
#(Tested with 100 rows and 30 columns.)
```

I expect it to be more efficient, but it's definitely more readable.